# $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ acting on bilinear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $V,W$ be a finite dimensional real linear spaces, and $\beta:V\times V\to W$ a bilinear map. Then my notes claim that for $g\in\mathrm{GL}(V)$ we define $g\cdot\beta(u,v)=\beta(g^{-1}u,g^{-1}v)$, and then $(gh)\cdot\beta=g\cdot(h\cdot\beta)$. So we should have a left action of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ on the set of bilinear maps $V\times V\to W$.

But that doesn't seem right, we have $(gh)\cdot\beta(u,v)=\beta(h^{-1}g^{-1}u,h^{-1}g^{-1}v)$ and $g\cdot (h\cdot\beta)(u,v)=\beta(g^{-1}h^{-1}u,g^{-1}h^{-1}v)$.

Am I wrong or should this action be defined differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g \cdot (h \cdot \beta)(u, v) = (h \cdot \beta)(g^{-1}u, g^{-1}v) = \beta(h^{-1}g^{-1}u, h^{-1}g^{-1}v)$.